# Integrating GIS data in NETlogo

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing

I'm working on a simple virus model in NETlogo, and attempting to integrate spatial data. I'm hoping I can limit the "agents" to these polygons and base the number of them off of my population data. Currently, I've modified an existing model and have been able to add my polygons (and associated attribute information) by copying the code from the provided "segregation" model in the NETlogo library.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-constants
  setup-turtles
  update-global-variables
  update-display
  gis:load-coordinate-system "data/LA_Harbor_Region.prj"
  set city-dataset gis:load-dataset "data/LA_Harbor_Region.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of city-dataset


  ;;copy the color information to patches (converting vector to raster)
  gis:apply-coverage city-dataset "SOC" mycolor
  gis:apply-coverage city-dataset "DISTRICT" DISTRICT

    ;; each polygon identifies a patch at its centroid, which records the color
  ;; and population here
  let n 1
  foreach gis:feature-list-of city-dataset [
    feature ->
    let center-point gis:location-of gis:centroid-of feature
    ask patch item 0 center-point item 1 center-point [
      set centroid? true
      set popu gis:property-value feature "POP65UP"
    ]
    set n n + 1
  ]
```

It does appear the model was able to read the data to draw the polygons/map, separate the census tracts and apply the color modifiers I requested. However, I am unable to get the model to do little else. This is the code section I believe controls the initial population/location in the "segregation" model with some modifications.

```
;; Find neighbors using a txt file produced by ArcGIS Polygon Neighbors.
  ;; Please read NETLOGO FEATURES in info tab for more information.

  ask patches with [centroid? = true] [
    set myneighbors n-of 0 patches ;;empty agentset
  ]

  file-close
  file-open "data/neighbors.txt"

  while [not file-at-end?] [
    let x file-read let y file-read
    ask patches with [ centroid? = true and DISTRICT = x ] [
      set myneighbors (patch-set myneighbors patches with [centroid? = true and DISTRICT = y ])
    ]
  ]
  file-close

  ask patches with [centroid? = true] [
    if count myneighbors = 0 [print "ERROR"]
  ]

  ;;use this line to verify if we get the right neighbors
  ;ask one-of patches with [centroid? = true] [print myneighbors   ask myneighbors [sprout 1]]

  ;;fill in the color on themap
  
  foreach gis:feature-list-of city-dataset [
    feature ->
    if gis:property-value feature "SOC" = "RED" [
      gis:set-drawing-color 15  gis:fill feature 2.0
    ]
    if gis:property-value feature "SOC" = "BLUE" [
      gis:set-drawing-color 95  gis:fill feature 2.0
    ]
    if gis:property-value feature "SOC" = "GREY" [
      gis:set-drawing-color 7  gis:fill feature 2.0
    ]
    if gis:property-value feature "SOC" = "BLACK" [
      gis:set-drawing-color 99  gis:fill feature 2.0
    ]
    if gis:property-value feature "SOC" = "YELLOW" [
      gis:set-drawing-color 45  gis:fill feature 2.0
    ]
  ]

  ;; Draw boundary
  gis:set-drawing-color white
  gis:draw city-dataset 1

   ;; Creating households
  ask patches with [DISTRICT > 0] [set occupied? false]

  let y 1
  while [y <= 188] [

    ;; Find the population and initial colour of all of the patches inside this polygon
    let popu1 [popu] of patches with [centroid? = true and DISTRICT = y]
    let color1 [mycolor] of patches with [centroid? = true and DISTRICT = y]

    if color1 = ["RED"] [
      ;; This is a red polygon. Make 50% of the turtles red and the remaining 50% blue.
      ask n-of (0.5 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [
        sprout 1 [
          set tID y
          set tcolor "RED"
          set color red
          set size 2
          ask patch-here [ set occupied? true ]
        ]
      ]
      ask n-of (0.5 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [
        sprout 1 [
          set tID y
          set tcolor "BLUE"
          set color blue
          set size 2
          ask patch-here [ set occupied? true ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    if color1 = ["BLUE"] [
      ;; Same code as above, but this time make 60% blue and 40% red
      ask n-of (0.6 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "BLUE" set color blue set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
      ask n-of (0.4 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "RED"  set color red  set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
    ]
    if color1 = ["GREY"] [
      ;; Same code as above, but this time make 90% blue and 10% red
      ask n-of (0.9 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "BLUE" set color blue set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
      ask n-of (0.1 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "RED"  set color red  set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
    ]
    if color1 = ["BLACK"] [
      ;; Same code as above, but this time make 75% blue and 25% red
      ask n-of (0.75 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "BLUE" set color blue set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
      ask n-of (0.25 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "RED"  set color red  set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
    ]
    if color1 = ["YELLOW"] [
      ;; Same code as above, but this time make 60% blue and 40% red
      ask n-of (0.6 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "BLUE" set color blue set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
      ask n-of (0.4 *(item 0 popu1 / 10)) patches with [DISTRICT = y and occupied? = false] [sprout 1 [set tID y set tcolor "RED"  set color red  set size 2 ask patch-here[set occupied? true]]]
    ]
    set y y + 1
  ]


  reset-ticks
end
```

I have no coding experience.

Comment: Please do not delete and repost. SE anti-spam defenses could lock you out. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395482/gis-netlogo-virus-model

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qR9lZy6xjE) shows you how to convert shape and raster files to .asc and then open them in NetLogo. One section of the code focuses on putting agents (sheep and wolves in this case) on the different patches created from QGIS.

You will need to look at [all the code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tonysdatamodels/netlogo.gis/main/netlogocode.open.gis) to understand how the globals and patch variables work (again see video), but for now the most relevant section of code can be found below.

```
;Ask forests to be brown
ask patches with [is-forest = 1][set pcolor brown - 1]

;Ask livestock farms to be green
ask patches with [is-farm = 1][set pcolor green + 3]
end

;Code used to setup wolf population in forest
to setup-wolf
create-wolfs wolf-population
 [set shape "wolf"
  set color black
  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = brown - 1]]
end

;Code used to setup sheep population on farms
to setup-sheep
create-sheeps sheep-population
 [set shape "sheep"
  set color white
  move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = green + 3]]
end
```